# Could someone stay in market points more than one turn?

Tags: timeline-cheapass-games

It's about the Timeline game from Cheapass Games.

Could a player stay on market points and somehow skip his/her turn for multiple turns, waiting for buying some goods for high value?

Comment: Rules are purportedly here, though I can't read them right now: http://cheapass.com/freegames/timeline

Comment: I have read that rules and still have this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The [rules](http://cheapass.com//wp-content/uploads/2016/07/TIMELINE-RULES.pdf) of the game state:

> You don’t have to sell anything in a market, and you can even sit still and sell something on the following turn if you so desire. For example, you expect that the 4 you’re now sitting in will be connected to Oilpetrol on the next turn, so you wait there in hopes of selling your Oilpetrol next turn.

The requirement for moving is stated in the rules as:

> On each turn, you may move your pawn.

So you never have to move if you don't want to, and the rules specifically say you can wait on a market space for a good's price to reach a high value.